# Display speed of a unity vuforia tracking target

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I just finished a Vuforia Unity AR project which successfully tracks a target and moves a unity object. 
I have done this using AR camera prefab and ImageTrack prefabs.

I have added a 3d sphere with the ImageTrack object. Upon detecting a marker, the sphere is displayed and faithfully follows target where ever it goes.
I want to display the position or speed of this moving sphere which appears and follows the target.

To start with that I have attached  a gui textbox with sphere with screenoverlay property.
I set `transform.position` to this text box and it shows the initial coordinates of ImageTrack when run. As the sphere moves upon marker moving, I want the current position of the sphere to be displayed.

Now it just shows initial position of the ImageTrack even though I placed the code under `update(){}`
I need latest current position because I need to calculate velocity, acceleration of this moving sphere.
Any help plz

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who may come here, the following code works for me:

```
private void Update()
{
    float x = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position).x / Screen.width;
    float y = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position).y / Screen.height;

    var tString  = "x = " + System.Math.Round(x, 4);
    var tString2 = "y = " + System.Math.Round(y, 4);

    winText.text  = tString;
    win2Text.text = tString2;
}
```